# Ajax XMLHttpRequest.open Not Being Called

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have some javascript code  where I have 2 ajax calls setup, below is the ajax call that is not working:

```
var btn2 = document.getElementById('btn2');

btn2.addEventListener("click", function () {
    var OurRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    OurRequest.open('GET', 'http://localhost:49549/Home/SendBillInfoToThirdPartyApp');
    OurRequest.onload = function () {
        var sendStatus = JSON.parse(OurRequest.responseText);

        console.log(sendStatus.status);
    };
});
```

The below html is the button that will trigger the event:

```
<button id="btn2">YO</button>
```

And finally here the Controller action method that handles the GET request:

```
public JsonResult SendBillInfoToThirdPartyApp()
        {
            var sendStatus = RealEstateInvestmentEligibilityCheck.SendBillInfo();

            return Json(new{ status = sendStatus }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

So the problem is when I click the YO button I expect the `SendBillInfoToThirdPartyApp` method to be called. But when I click the button and follow the request (by adding breakpoint in chrome dev tools) it goes to the `OurRequest.open()` and then stops.

But when I copy the GET request (http://localhost:49549/Home/SendBillInfoToThirdPartyApp) and paste it in a separate chrome tab the code will begin executing at my breakpoint in VS at the action method. I have another ajax call setup similar to this one in the same javascript file that works fine.

Any ideas on why this ajax call isn't being triggered?

Comment: Is page running on same port request is being made to?

Comment: Yes, I copied the url from the Web section in the project properties.

Comment: Not necessarily the same thing but ok